# SCP command to move directories from local machine to server

Tags: terminal, server, scp

I am using a macbook air terminal (my local machine) to transfer over a directory with a large number of images onto a server. The images are located two subdirectores called "folder1" and "folder2" under `/Users/viv/images/data.` 
I want to copy the contents of this directory over to a server that I can ssh into. I ssh into it using the command `ssh udacity@54.91.119.34`
My question is how do I copy the contents of my local machine onto the server, I tried using the following command:

```
scp -r /Users/viv/images/data udacity@54.91.119.34
```

But this ends up creating a new directory called udacity$54.91.119.34 and copying the contents of the data directory onto my local machine itself
Please adice on how I should proceed so the data can be copied onto the server.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add a colon at the end, followed by the destination directory (leave blank for the home directory of the user):

```
scp -r /Users/viv/images/data udacity@54.91.119.34:
```